# SPUtility.SearchPrincipals very slow

Tags: search, user-profile

I'm trying to create a "Search for Users" function that is supposed to hit the SharePoint User Profile Store (running SP2010 Enterprise). However, that function takes up to a Minute to search, which is WAY too long. I found a weird [50-Step Process flow diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357076%28v=PROT.13%29.aspx) that doesn't make much sense since I'm not using Foundation but the full server, in which case searching should be a simple SELECT against the Profile Database and return in a few ms?

Comment: I am not clear why, but I have found the same, also using the Enterprise version of SharePoint.

Comment: Where is your Domain Controller located?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is the link to Active Directory that is the problem, particularly if your Domain Controller is not near (in the sense of network latency) to your SharePoint server(s).

Comment: That's interesting. Yes, some domain controllers are not near (multiple domains in the forest), but I don't understand why it hits AD at all when there is the user profile database right there for sharepoint to query in a millisecond or two?

Comment: I think in essence the profile is holding attributes of the user but it is still relying on AD (or other authentication provider) to supply the identity, and I assume this is what the API you are calling is iterating over. The way user profiles work is a bit of a mystery.